# Where/how can you see an enemy's level in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I keep seeing all these questions referring to enemy levels in Fallout 4 and how people killed a monster or enemy at level XX - how do you know/detect what level the enemy is? I have looked in settings and over the perk list and saw nothing immediate about enemy levels.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The level 3 Perception perk "Awareness" will allow you to see the enemy level as well as their resistances when viewing the enemy through V.A.T.S.:

[image: V.A.T.S showing awareness]

Comment: Huh...I wish it would say that haha I will try it when I play tonight then.

Comment: Really wish we could at least get the level without the perk. There's other perks that are dependent upon enemy level, so it seems we should have some way of determining that without having to spend another point.